# trying to get the calculator to return 0 not an error message when a number is divided by 0?

Tags: java

Here is the problem in a nut shell. I have made a basic calculator in Java and I am trying to get the calculator to return 0 when a number is entered and it is divided by 0. Each time I keep getting an error message!

```
class Calculator
{

long sum;

public void evaluate( char action, long number )
{
    if (action == '+')
    {
        sum = number + number;

    }

    if (action == '-')
    {
        sum = number - number;

    }

    if (action == '*')
    {
        sum = number * number;

    }

    if (action == '/')
    {
        sum = number / number;

    }

    **if (sum == number / 0)
    {
        sum = 0;
    }
}**
```

Comment: You define just one number and use this twice? If you want to avoid the division by zero, test if number == 0...

Comment: So you've made a basic calculator that can return 0, 1, n-squared or 2n, and now you want it to return a wrong answer in one specific scenario? WTF?

Comment: Any number divided by zero == infinity. Division by zero errors are common, and this is a case you will need to test for throughout your career.

Comment: Just a thought, you could wrap the code that calls the method in a try catch block, then catch the division by zero error and respond appropriately.

Comment: @superluminary That is not exactly true, any number divided by zero is undefined, not infinity

Comment: @superluminary to add to what NominSim said, it depends on the structure you're considering but on (extended) real line that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

**With [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript) operator:**

```
if (action == '/') {
    sum = number == 0 ? 0 : number / number;  // <-- isn't that just 1 ?  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add this logic to your division code:

```
if (action == '/')
{
    if (number == 0)
    {
        sum = 0;
    } else {
        sum = number / number;
    }
}
```

Also, why are you using the same number per operation? The subtraction operator will always return `0`. If you are using this code in a calculator, just check whether the denominator is `0`.

Comment: Trouble is x / 0 != 0, it's infinity.

Comment: The division operator (in mathematics) isn't defined for zero at all. The *limit* of `a / b` as `b -> +0` is `inf`, but it is undefined to divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (action == '/')
{
    if(number2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("You cannot divide by 0!");
        return;
    }
    sum = number1 / number2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE 754 standard includes not only positive and negative numbers that consist of a sign and magnitude, but also positive and negative zeros, positive and negative infinities, and special Not-a-Number values (hereafter abbreviated NaN). A NaN value is used to represent the result of certain invalid operations such as dividing zero by zero. NaN constants of both float and double type are predefined as Float.NaN and Double.NaN.

You need to add condition make sure you are not dividing by ZERO.

```
if(secondnumber == 0)
    {

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, why not catch the exception (and use java coding conventions) ?

```
if (action == '/') {
     try {
        sum = number / number;
     catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        //log error
        sum = 0;
     }
}
```

The bonus here is that it handles whatever else wrong could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Simple check:

```
public double div(char action, int numerator, int dinominator){

  double ans=0;

  if(action == '/'){

    if(dinominator == 0){
         ans=0;
    } else {
         ans = numerator / dinominator;
    }

  }
  return ans;
}
```